# Why is the Covariance operator continuous?

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, measure-theory, proof-explanation, stochastic-analysis

> Claim: Covariance operator $C_\mu : B^*\to B^{**}$ is continuous.

$B$ is a Banach space and $B^*$ its dual space.

For clarification the original def. of the covariance operator is:
$C_\mu: B^* \times B^* \to \mathbb{R}$
$~~~~~~~(l, l') \to \int_Bl(x)~~l'(x)~ \mu(dx)$
but here it is identified as
$C_\mu: B^* \to B^{**} = (B^*)^*$ given by $C_\mu(l)(l') := C_\mu (l, l')$
Proof:  Let $l\in B^*$. Then
 $$\begin{align*}|| C_\mu(l)||_{B^{**}}&=  \sup_{||l||_{B^*}\leq1}~|\int_B l(x)l'(x) ~\mu(dx)| \\
&\leq \sup_{||l||_{B^*}\leq1}~ \int_B |l(x)|~ |l'(x)| \mu(dx)
\end{align*}$$

Until now everything is clear but then the next approximation is:
$$~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~\leq ||l||_{B^*}~\int_B ||x||^2 ~\mu(dx)$$
Then we have shown that the operator is continuous because $\int_B ||x||^2 ~\mu(dx)$ is finite (Fernique).
I would like to understand the last estimation. My guess is
$$sup_{||l||_{B^*}\leq1}~~|l(x)| \leq ||l||_{B^*} ||x||_B$$
$$|l'(x)|\leq ||x||_{B}$$
but i have no clue why this should hold. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: l' is an element of the dual space ($B^*$).

Comment: I have edited my question such that the def. of l' should be clear now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$ \rVert C_\mu(l) \rVert_{B^{**}} = \sup_{\Vert l' \rVert_{B^*}\leq 1} \int_B |l(x)|~ |l'(x)|\,\mu(dx)
$$
The condition $\Vert l' \rVert_{B^*}\leq 1$ in the supremum can be changed to $\Vert l' \rVert_{B^*}= 1$ by the equivalent definitions of norms. Thus $\Vert l' \rVert_{B^*} = 1$, and $|l'(x)| \leq \lVert x \rVert_B$. We can simplify by dicarding $l'$ completely.
$$ \leq \int_B |l(x)| \lVert x \rVert_B \,\mu(dx)
$$ 
Then, from the definition of norm, $\lVert l x \rVert \leq \lVert l \rVert_{B^*} \lVert x \rVert_B$, so (Here, $\lVert l x \rVert = |lx|$)
$$ \leq \int_B \lVert l \rVert_{B^*} \lVert x \rVert_B \lVert x \rVert_B \,\mu(dx) = \lVert l \rVert_{B^*} \int_B \lVert x \rVert_B^2 \,\mu(dx)
$$

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you please further elaborate why for the B*-norm
|| lx ||= | lx |
in general holds?

Comment: @user322455 $lx$ is a scalar. (Either $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$) The topology on scalars is induced by the absolute value norm.